# How to change input shape in CNN image from 40x40 to 13x78?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

This CNN works well for 40x40x2 images, but now i want to change to 13x78x2 and get the following error. What should i change in the architecture of my CNN?

```
Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 2 for 'conv2d_13/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,2,35,64], [3,3,64,64].
```

My code:

```
  data_w = 40 #CHANGE TO 13
  data_h = 40 #CHANGE TO 78
  n_classes = 2
  n_filters_1 = 32
  n_filters_2 = 64
  d_filter = 3
  p_drop_1 = 0.25
  p_drop_2 = 0.50   
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Convolution2D(n_filters_1, d_filter, d_filter, border_mode='valid', input_shape=(data_w, data_h,2)))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(Convolution2D(n_filters_1, d_filter, d_filter))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(Dropout(p_drop_1))
  model.add(Convolution2D(n_filters_2, d_filter, d_filter, border_mode='valid'))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(Convolution2D(n_filters_2, d_filter, d_filter))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(Dropout(p_drop_1))
  ## Used to flat the input (1, 10, 2, 2) -> (1, 40)
  model.add(Flatten())
  # Full Connected layer
  model.add(Dense(256))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  # Drop layer
  model.add(Dropout(p_drop_2))
  # Output Full Connected layer
  model.add(Dense(n_classes))
  model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have chosen `valid` as the `border_mode` for the convolution, what will happen is that with your 3 x 3 filter size, we will thus remove 1 pixel around the borders for the generated filter outputs at each `Convolution2D` layer.  Also note that omitting the argument assumes valid padding as well. If you work out the reduction in output sizes at each layer, you will get to a point where one of the dimensions (the rows) of the output filter sizes will be 0 and thus you get the error.  With `d_filter = 3`, let's walk through the output filter sizes at each layer given the input image size is 13 x 78.  Please note that I omit showing the filter size outputs at the `Activation` and `Dropout` layers since we already know that they maintain the same output sizes as what goes in for brevity:

```
  model.add(Convolution2D(n_filters_1, d_filter, d_filter, border_mode='valid', input_shape=(data_w, data_h,2))) # 11 x 76
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(Convolution2D(n_filters_1, d_filter, d_filter)) # 9 x 74
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) # 4 x 37
  model.add(Dropout(p_drop_1))
  model.add(Convolution2D(n_filters_2, d_filter, d_filter, border_mode='valid')) # 2 x 35
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(Convolution2D(n_filters_2, d_filter, d_filter)) # 0 x 33 (!!!!)
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(Dropout(p_drop_1))
```

One immediate thing I would suggest is  changing the `border_mode` so that it's `'same'`.  That way, the output filter sizes are maintained for each `Convolution2D` layer before it hits a Pooling layer.  I am unsure as to your purpose of choosing valid convolution, but try doing this:

```
  model.add(Convolution2D(n_filters_1, d_filter, d_filter, border_mode='same', input_shape=(data_w, data_h,2))) # 13 x 78
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(Convolution2D(n_filters_1, d_filter, d_filter), border_mode='same') # 13 x 78
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) # 6 x 39
  model.add(Dropout(p_drop_1))
  model.add(Convolution2D(n_filters_2, d_filter, d_filter, border_mode='same')) # 6 x 39
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(Convolution2D(n_filters_2, d_filter, d_filter), border_mode='same') # 6 x 39
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) # 3 x 19
  model.add(Dropout(p_drop_1))
```

If not, you'll need to remove some `Convolution2D` and `MaxPooling2D` layers so that you can generate filter outputs that are non-zero.  Do the same work that I did above to figure out how many you need to remove the layers you need.  I would suggest removing the layers after the first `Convolution2D` and `Activation` layers with `n_filters_2` filters:

```
  model.add(Convolution2D(n_filters_1, d_filter, d_filter, border_mode='valid', input_shape=(data_w, data_h,2))) # 11 x 76
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(Convolution2D(n_filters_1, d_filter, d_filter)) # 9 x 74
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) # 4 x 37
  model.add(Dropout(p_drop_1))
  model.add(Convolution2D(n_filters_2, d_filter, d_filter, border_mode='valid')) # 2 x 35
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
#  model.add(Convolution2D(n_filters_2, d_filter, d_filter)) # 0 x 33 (!!!!)
#  model.add(Activation('relu'))
#  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
#  model.add(Dropout(p_drop_1))
```

Comment: border_mode='same' solved the problem. Thank you :)